# How to update Tkinter Combobox value from button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

#### I'm struggling when trying to update my combobox values. I want my removable disk lists to be updated when I click a button, not when the application starts.

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess as sub

root = Tk()

def list_disks():
    global disks
    disks = []
    output = sub.check_output(["lsblk", "-d", "-n", "-oNAME,TYPE,SIZE,RM"])
    for line in output.splitlines():
        name, blk_type, size, removable = line.split()
        if removable == b'1':
            disks.append(str(name.decode())+" "+str(size.decode()))
    return disks

def refresh():
    new_disks = []
    new_output = sub.check_output(["lsblk", "-d", "-n", "-oNAME,TYPE,SIZE,RM"])
    for line in new_output.splitlines():
        name, blk_type, size, removable = line.split()
        if removable == b'1':
            new_disks.append(str(name.decode())+" "+str(size.decode()))
    evidence['values']=new_disks

opts = StringVar()
evidence = Combobox(root, values=list_disks(),variable=opts)
evidence.pack()
refresh = custom.CTkButton(root, image = search ,text="refresh",command=refresh)
refresh.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you don't want to update the combobox when the application starts, remove `values=list_disks()` from `Combobox(...)`.  Also it is better to provide a [mre] as your posted code failed to run due to undefined `Combobox` because you did not import `Combobox` from `ttk`.

Comment: @acw1668 `*` was imported from `tkinter`, so there wouldn't be an error. Maybe it is the compiler you are running it in which throws the error, or some other reason.

Comment: @AlphaA999 Do you know that `Combobox` is a widget from tkinter *sub-module* `ttk` which is not imported by `from tkinter import *`? Did you try it yourself?  Also note that `Python` is not a compiler.